# Android + Firebase Auth + REST API: How to properly work with token?

Tags: android, api, firebase, firebase-authentication, restful-authentication

I'm starting a new project and Firebase Auth was the choice for authentication. The idea is to create/login users through Firebase Auth and then, use the Firebase ID Token to authenticate on my backend (through Authentication header).

In Google Samples, this is the way I should get the token:

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

But, as you can see, this is a async call, because it goes to Firebase servers to get me the Token. So, every REST API call to my backend, I need to run the above code, because I don't know when the token has expired.

Is there a better way to safety call my backend REST APIs using Firebase Auth? Or using the Firebase ID Token is the best one? If so, how should I wrap this id token get for every REST API call?

If you have a better way to authenticate users to call rest apis later, I'm all ears.

Comment: which tech is your backend written on? I suppose you can alter code in there too?

Comment: @LeviAlbuquerque the backend is new too. We are writing it on .net core. Again, if there's any other tech better for this situation, I'm all ears.

Comment: If you backend was one of the supported ones by the admin sdk you could manage sign in in a more simpler manner https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens But for that you'd need to have a python, go, node.js or java backend which are natively supported

Comment: Maybe I can mix two backend tech: .net core and go. What do you think?

Comment: I don't think that would be wise. But let me ask you something, how were you planing to confirm the id token that the user had sent?

Comment: OK. On .net core, we can call a firebase service to ask: is this id token authenticated? If firebase says yes, we deliver the user the success response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171037/discussion-between-levi-albuquerque-and-guilherme-lima-pereira).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the Idea is quite simple. You can use this method in the Android device as you already know:

```
FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
mUser.getIdToken(true)
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GetTokenResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                String idToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
                // ...
            } else {
                // Handle error -> task.getException();
            }
        }
    });
```

Once you hold the instance of the token you send it to your backend for authentication there, it will authenticate only once and send you backend a token that is managed by the backend itself. That's the token that will be sent in each subsequent call to the backend, not the generated by the above method.

Comment: that's quite a bad idea and destroy the first purpose of using FirebaseAuth. A preferable approach is to create a firebase custom token. But the best approach is probably to listen to the firebase on token change or check if Firebase de facto always async.

Comment: Do you have an example or a blog link? I don't quite understand the protocol. This accepted answer is taking advantage of using Google Auth, Facebook Auth, etc easily from Android. But how do you move on after that if you have a custom API with your own database for everything else but authentication?